# Swifty Argument Labels

Tags: code-golf, string, swift

> For the purpose of this challenge, *arguments* are things you pass to a function at the call site, while *parameters* are what the function uses in its implementation. Or, more succinctly: arguments = external, parameters = internal.

While there are several modern languages that have support for argument labels for functions at the call site, Swift's implementation of argument labels is unique. In essence, the *argument label* (external) and the *parameter name* (internal) are not necessarily related to each other. (There's also the fact that argument labels are *required* to be used at the call site, but that's unimportant for this challenge.)

### The Challenge

Write a program or function that receives two strings as input (an argument label, and a parameter name); and outputs (or returns) a single string containing a valid Swift function parameter declaration (sans the type annotation).

#### Requirements

[Here's the official documentation for Swift parameter declarations, if you’re curious.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/declarations#Parameter-Names) You only have to implement a very small subset of this.

- If `argumentLabel` and `parameterName` are equal, simply output their shared value.
- If `argumentLabel` and `parameterName` are *not* equal, output `argumentLabel`, followed by a space, followed by `parameterName`.
- If `argumentLabel` and/or `parameterName` are empty, replace the empty value(s) with an underscore (`_`), then follow the rules above.

Here's an example implementation in (what else?) Swift.

```swift
func parameterDeclaration(
  label argumentLabel: String,
  name parameterName: String
) -> String {
  switch (argumentLabel, parameterName) {
  case ("", ""):
    "_"
  case ("", _):
    "_ \(parameterName)"
  case (_, ""):
    "\(argumentLabel) _"
  case _ where argumentLabel == parameterName:
    parameterName
  default:
    "\(argumentLabel) \(parameterName)"
  }
}
```

#### Rules

- All the [usual IO methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/118665) are allowed.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/118665) are, of course, forbidden.
- You may assume that both input strings consist exclusively of ASCII letters (uppercase and lowercase) and digits. (That is, they match this regex: `/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/`.) **You may *not* assume, however, that the strings will be nonempty.**
- You may take input as a tuple, a list, two separate arguments, a single string with a separator, or any other method that allows you to receive two separate strings as input.

  - Please mention your input method in your answer, as well as the order of inputs (argument label before parameter name, or vice versa).

### Test Cases

In these test cases, the first item is the argument label, the second is the parameter name, and the third is the expected output.

```swift
("do",     "body")   -> "do body"
("a123",   "b456")   -> "a123 b456"
("count",  "count")  -> "count"
("arg1",   "arg1")   -> "arg1"
("",       "number") -> "_ number"
("unused", "")       -> "unused _"
("",       "")       -> "_"
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so, as per usual, shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: FWIW OCaml also doesn't require the argument label to match the parameter name, though it does provide a convenient shorthand for that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 6 bytes

```
₉'_ru„
```

Trivial implementation.
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLigoknX3J14oCeIiwiIiwiW1widW51c2VkXCIsIFwiXCJdIiwiMy40LjIiXQ==)

```
₉'_ru„­⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
   r    # ‎⁡Replace
₉       # ‎⁢empty string by
 '_     # ‎⁣underscore
    u„  # ‎⁤Uniquify and join on spaces
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
f""="_"
f x=x
a#b=unwords$f a:[f b|a/=b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/NCsIwDAfwe58iZB42GMr8Ogh9Az15HEPatVVx60Y/cAPffa7Ti8NcEvLjD8mN2YesqmFQiBQvSBR0tCMs4tTrZ2OEXShgh1wBf7EV5cXgpHUWKOQQo2gwBeSN6DEh8K10BJatNxNtd/sZlY3XLthnmOXMNQs29V8Ka@1rLs0MvPZWisB/EphAQUjN7no8uWbtCeLWu7MzRw1L8Lr0xvQQR0kC02PDGw) I borrowed the test suite from totallyhuman.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 41 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(a!=b)*f"{a or'_'} "+(b or"_")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY_PasMwDMbvfQpNl9hdMtb9YxRS6GUw2GHQY1eCvThbILGNm4yVsYfYeZdeunfqC-w5KtuhUJ2kTz99kn7_7KZ7N3q7qyCHl13fVdn9njeilaUAkcopE2e55OMKvwQYlxTJN-A5k5RjgXwY-KmMg6bWCmoNxirNLvl0BBS1timoT0vurbBMfYgmDeTF2jZ1xxLIZpBwHmDTd8RVbExTUbGu1h1b4sP88QlTwOf5YoGrZQBz77tK44okmyUpOGUdoyYfDtvu_xmWhiZ9oDTlBjlltJNkCPWIoZhcXQcG5c3t3ZHwMgSFmFfT685DQ8YjEwvv4d4m0SNkRw9fUHs4gdq6b6VyBPh2AUNJSK_7tSr9l2EaBocoQ3HqcoIUGN89AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 37 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>(x||'_')+(x==y?'':y?' '+y:' _')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7JCoMwFEX3/YpHNkmordiJIsTu9DPECWmxSXEiAf/d5kUR2izCHU4ueWVj1hXt89Mfxvsci1mLyIiI6WmiKeV7poUwD0pDewHdm5CCjedEMO0ZLqJCyU411bFRNYuZ5sxwvksYKRXxAA/JVWkIt8r3wcbgPCJZcDo7iOSX621DMAaXIFSoQfZIrYov0GLcSlsHy4pT2woa7Ndv2F4O77xqLYF9CqtFZpBDV5WWJO49rBtLDOnfzg9jy/kL)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
""#b="_"#b
a#""=a#"_"
a#b|a==b=a|1>0=a++' ':b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/NCsIwDADge58iZIetbIjz7yDUJ9CTR5HRuqLi1o3@HAZ799pOLw5zSEI@AsmDm5dsGu8RE8GwCpnwBJGFVGFoxcgZE4yP5WHJeJ6nkO6Ft9JYAwwukGHdYQEounpASuAbRQBertYTbba7Gd06p2y0TzPb0/cy2lR/KY6Va4XUM3DKGVlH/rOBFK6EtPypwskt70@Q9c6erT4qWIBTN6f1AFlCKUyP@Tc)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 6 bytes

```
ȯ€”_QK
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLIr+KCrOKAnV9RSyIsIsOH4oKsWSIsIiIsWyJbXG5bXCJkb1wiLCBcImJvZHlcIl0sXG5bXCJhMTIzXCIsIFwiYjQ1NlwiXSxcbltcImNvdW50XCIsIFwiY291bnRcIl0sXG5bXCJhcmcxXCIsIFwiYXJnMVwiXSxcbltcIlwiLCBcIm51bWJlclwiXSxcbltcInVudXNlZFwiLCBcIlwiXSxcbltcIlwiLCBcIlwiXVxuXSJdXQ==)

#### Explanation

```
ȯ€”_QK    Main Link
ȯ         logical OR (flat)
 €        each
  ”_      with "_"
    Q     uniquify
     K    join on space
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>66</s> 65 bytes

```java
a->b->(a.isEmpty()?"_":a)+(a.equals(b)?"":b.isEmpty()?" _":" "+b)
```

-1 byte porting [*@l4m2's JavaScript answer*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272118/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZE/T8MwEMX3forTTbaSWir/hhbCBBtTR4rQOUkrl8QJsV0pQv3swU6MaAYkJj/f753unX2kEy2PxceQV2QMvJDSXwsAY8mqHI6eCmdVJfZO51Y1WjxHcb@1ndKH9B@W6cgy2MPDQMtMLjNGQpmnurU944/4jmviia@Vn44qw6Sv4VpeWsB7EDCRfNgsfMDWycoHjDlPjSqg9tnZNOv1jXhYA8CWxjIsGkzDDVA2RY98c8FodXU9UpQ3t3dzljdO2wCjmjd2h9XUOKoZi@M8066WZTenTjtTFt6Df3VN9fPi9yvGFUfbtCJQfFeQcdVtb2xZi8ZZ0XpgK82Q7RATSnCHaVAyKL6GoPeC2rbqGfEoJA/0Z/J5@AY)

**Original answer:**

```java
(a,b)->(a=a.isEmtpy()?"_":a).equals(b=b.isEmtpy()?"_":b)?a:a+" "+b
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZE9b4MwEIb3/IrTTbYgSOnXQEQzdWyWjk1VncGNSMFQbEdCVX47tR1noFEW67Wf@3h9d6AjLQ/V91Q2pDW8Uq1@FwC1MnL4olLC1l8B3sxQqz2ULApKoxB87QJOC3doQ6YuYQsKiolRKvjymVFBWa1fWtOPjG/wE3Pimfyx1GgmCvGPCb6hnBIETMS09kV7KxpXNNY@dnUFrTMZfbx/ED8bNFIbhlWHqb8Biq4aMXi7MFrd3QeK4uHxac7KzirjYVTzxGG/OicGNWOxnWPKtkIOc2qV1bJyMXgrC6/GF74Ywq5HHXcxaiPbrLMm6x0wjWLIdoiJG9wOU6@EVzwHr1VWhmX4p0u70/QH)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->                 // Method with two String parameters & String return-type
  (a.isEmpty()?        //  If `a` is "":
    "_"                //   Start with "_" instead
   :                   //  Else:
    a)                 //   Start with `a`
      +                //  And append:
       (a.equals(b)?   //   If `a` and `b` are the same:
         ""            //    Append nothing more
        :b.isEmpty()?  //   Else-if `b` is "":
         " _"          //    Append a space and "_"
        :              //   Else (`a` and `b` are different, and `b` is not ""):
         " "+b)        //    Append a space and `b`
```

```java
(a,b)->                 // Method with two String parameters & String return-type
  (a=                   //  Overwrite `a` with:
     a.isEmtpy()?       //   If `a` is "":
      "_"               //    Replace it with "_"
     :                  //   Else:
      a)                //    Keep `a` the same
        .equals(        //  Check whether it equals:
   b=b.isEmtpy()?"_":b) //   Overwrite `b` in a similar matter
  ?                     //  If the modified `a` and `b` are the same:
   a                    //   Simply return the modified `a` as result
  :                     //  Else (they are different):
   a+" "+b              //   Return `a` and `b` joined by a space
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 25 bytes

Prompts for a nested vector of the argument name followed by the parameter name.

```
(≡/m)↓m←(×¨⍴¨m)↓¨'_',¨m←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv8ajzoX6uZqP2ibnAgU1Dk8/tOJR75ZDK8BCh1aox6vrADlAKaC@/0AdXP/TuNRT8tUV1JPyUyrVuYC8REMjYxDfxNQMzE/OL80rAQpAaLCKonRDoACYAvGB7LzS3KTUIjCvNK@0ODUFKAaTUwcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) 0.10.0, 21 bytes

```
/$"_ _"⍚⍥⋅@_=0⍚⧻.◴⊂∩□
```

### [Explanation + See it in action](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__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)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ùõ¸'_‡ðý
```

Input as a pair of strings.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//8OZw7XCuCdf4oChw7DDvf//WyIiLCJudW1iZXIiXQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/wzMPbz20Qz3@UcPCwxsO7/2v8z86WiklX0lHKSk/pVIpVkchWinR0MgYJGBiagYRSM4vzSsBikDoWAWwoqJ0Q6AQmAIrAnLySnOTUosg3NK80uLUFKAgXFYpNhYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ù         # Uniquift the (implicit) input-pair
 õ¸       # Push [""]
   '_    '# Push "_"
     ‡    # Replace all "" items with "_"
      ðý  # Join the list with " " delimiter
          # (after which the result-string is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 54 bytes

Well of *course* I needed to golf my own Swift answer, this is the language I speak.

```swift
let u={$0>"" ?$0:"_"},f={u($0)+($0==$1 ?"":" "+u($1))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCoMwEETv@YplySFBD6a1PQipH1JK0ZoUQWOJCaWI326jlUqhe1iGNzML2z9r7dJpapQDLweanBAhp0mGVxxjLQfPaMKjsKSkAnLEDAGjQAXn41Jzqnc9SDgTCMOw6jCeFWDZVS/k8coLsdsvDpbp4bjxW@eNm41VbQV7F5/Cor58PR@48W2p7OZ443tVBR//pZGTC9GdBdYUpWpiMEWrONRmfWFYGg9bG8f0T4aTcXoD)

`f(_:_:)` is the closure you’re looking for. Argument label comes first, parameter label comes second.

This ended up being in the same vein as [@l4m2's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2) [JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/272118/118665). I bind a closure to `u` up front that replaces an empty string with an underscore, before calling it with the first parameter, checking if the parameters are equal, and then calling it again (prepending a space) if they're not.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 17 bytes

```
%`^$
_
D`
G`.
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg8181IU6FK57LJYHLPUGP69A2LoX//1PydZLyUyq5Eg2NjHWSTEzNuJLzS/NKdMAkV2JRuqEOiODSySvNTUot4irNKy1OTdHh0gEA) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on commas for convenience. Explanation:

```
%`^$
_
```

Replace empty lines with `_`s.

```
D`
G`.
```

Deduplicate and remove any resulting trailing empty line.

```
¶
```

If there are still two lines, join them with a space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
⪫…⟦∨θ_∨η_⟧⊕¬⁼θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPw7kyOSfVOSO/QCPav0ijUEdBKV5JU0cByM6AsGN1FDzzkotSc1PzSlJTNPzySzRcC0sTc4pBijM0gQCoTkFJU9P6/3@uvNLcpNSi/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    θ               First input
   ∨                Logical Or
     _              Literal string `_`
       η            Second input
      ∨             Logical Or
        _           Literal string `_`
  ⟦      ⟧          Make into list
 …                  Truncate to length
             θ      First input
            ⁼       Equals
              η     Second input
           ¬        Logical Not
          ⊕         Incremented
⪫                   Join on spaces
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 37 bytes

```perl
$_=($;=<>||"_")ne($_||="_")?"$_
$;":$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZDxdrWxq6mRileSTMvVUMlvqbGFsS2V1KJ51KxVrJS@f8/KbGIKy0//19@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/ugU5AA)